# unable to connect firefox driver with given url

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have wrote the following code.
But whenever i am going to run the code some error got generated and the generated error are given below.

```
    ***package techAltum;
    import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    public class JabongSearchBox {
        WebDriver driver;
        String url;


        @Before
            public void launchBrowser(){
                //Open Browser
/*i am getting error at driver= new FirefoxDriver(). browser open but didn't get url.*/
                **driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.manage().window().maximize();

                url = "http://www.jabong.com";**

                driver.get(url);
            }
            @Test

        @After
        public void quitBrowser(){
            driver.quit();
        }

    }***
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use selenium 2.48.2 firefox seems to changed something in last 1 week update . I had an application using selenium that now fails in latest firefox as well.

I had that in the past , normally selenium guys will post a new version to support that sooner or later

Comment: currently i am using latest version of both. my all workspace programe also give same error (previously i have run perfectly) like new. i have checked for chrome , firefox, IE also and find same problem : browser open maximize but didn't get url , program terminated.

Comment: I have a problem that worked similar like charm 2 weeks ago , after an update to firefox broke it and i assume that something is changed to communication API from  selenium to Firefox. I guess we shall wait for an update from selenium guys

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve the problem, just initialize your `webdriver` like this:

```
WebDriver driver = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code working for me, i am using selenium 2.48.2 and Firefox 43.0.2. Please verify you are using latest selenium and Firefox. 
And if you face the issue again please post the error message this will us to know your issue better.